# TypeScript types - Retaining literal value throughout chain of types

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to compose a function signature, that doesn't accept literal numbers, just results of function call, as a tiny bonus feature for Test matcher lib that I am prototyping, and got in TS type rabbit hole a little bit

I have a type that transforms number into string, and then type that tells whether provided number was a literal number or just a number e.g. result of a function call

```
type Non_Literal_Number<Number extends string>
    = `${number}` extends Number
    ? number
    : never

type Number_To_String<N extends number> = `${N}`

type Test_Non_Literal = Non_Literal_Number<Number_To_String<number>> // number
type Test_Literal = Non_Literal_Number<Number_To_String<42>> // never
```

Next I have a test function providing number results, and then trying first approach just to test things and get a correct type in an auxiliary parameter, which works, but Ide doesn't react to it as never is allowed as type param:

```
function get_number() { return 0 }

function with_aux_param<Number extends number, 
    Aux extends Non_Literal_Number<Number_To_String<Number>>>(number: Number) {}

//function that gets number was used, so resulting Aux param is number
//function with_aux_param<number, number>(number: number): void
with_aux_param(get_number())

//here literal of 8 was used, so resulting Aux param is never
//function with_aux_param<8, never>(number: 8): void
with_aux_param(8)
```

The problem happens in the intended function signature, where passing a function argument, through other types - causes this information about literal value be lost, and is considered just a number, as far as I understand.

```
function intended_signature<Number extends number>
    (number: Non_Literal_Number<Number_To_String<Number>>) {}

//function intended_signature<number>(number: number): void
intended_signature(get_number())

//function intended_signature<number>(number: number): void
//expected:
//function intended_signature<3>(number: never): void
//here, the error should appear telling 3 cant be assigned 
//to never
intended_signature(3)
```

Is there any way how to retain this literal type information, or am I just out of luck here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your type parameter in a complicated conditional type will prevent typescript from inferring from it, so you end up with the constraint. You can get this to work by using an intersection of `N & T<N>` the for the parameter. This will let TS infer `N` as the first constituent of this intersection and use it in the second constituent.

```
function intended_signature<N extends number>
    (number: N & Non_Literal_Number<Number_To_String<N>>) {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwPoBkCWwICcCGAbJGAVwFsAjbAHmPOyggA9MEATAZyjeCzQQHMAfAFgAUFHFQAvFAAGAEgDeCUhSwBfGfSYRWHGqtESoAfijLaWQxIBcZiADdso0aEiwV2JABU4SAMrcvHzUWszsZh5YAlKyijAaziKu0F4QXISIqBjY+DHwyOiYuAT6VKVY3r4BPPyU5qoC0QD0TREWLuApacBZRbnS+b05JZHUkZX+gbUALABMjVAtdo6WIqIAZkQIAMbAaIhQfBA99dgAFACUUApQWMdEWAhQAAxQaombO3sHvGEQLEg2Gg+AgcMAHhAQowwhxTlErOIznDbDAoAAyWCZQrDQijcoTapBaiNK4Kd5rES-HQsf6A4Gg8F3M5HE6RS4XRJU1i0oEgsEQs4AZguQA)

Maybe a better approach is to also let the user know what the problem is though a string literal type:

```
type ErrorOnNumberLiteral<N extends number>
    = number extends N ? N : { error: `Literal types not allowed, found ${N}` }

function get_number() { return 0 }

function intended_signature<N extends number>
    (number: N & ErrorOnNumberLiteral<N>) {}

intended_signature(get_number())

intended_signature(3)
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ error: "Literal types not allowed, found 3"; }'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogTnA9nA8gOwHIFcC2AjCOAGQEthCBDAGwB4MoIAPctAEwGco1cC4A+ALAAoKKKgBeLj0INmENp3oB+KPQBcUAN4MEyDQANS5ONSihInNImBRqVRAHcIrADRQAZoixsoAEk0YAL76UIHCwu7eAMbAJIhoUADmEMAA+tz4hAAUAJRaUHApWHAJAAyh4UKRaDFxCSRoLKzOqewkiWgUwMUQdLJNltL8wmJQWRm8GvQAZLC6qJhDRpS0GHx5mmFCwg1NLW0dXT1ZyWkT2Tk5lbvyzayt7Z3dhVkAzFdCAPSfUAAq4NAAOTnOCAqAkSzWWzsA6dPBUaDARBmAFQQHaQhIOAaABEyxMVBRFi4ULsjmcbk83lYUFeOIA3KFAUA)

I don't 100% recommend this though, if your goal is for the value to come from a function call this only somewhat overlaps with that goal, it bans literal types, but literal types may also come from other variables or functions.  Maybe branded types would be a better solution.

Comment: 'never' was just to be consise, I do prototype it with string message. Your answer pretty much matches exactly what I wanted to achieve, goal here was truly just not the user assign literal value to received parameter, only to expected, so this will work great for what I want, thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, now I see, returning something like 1 | 2 | 3 from functions will be considered an error, well at least I understand this part of TS better now.

Comment: @Jarek yeah, if you return `1|2|3` it will be an error.